# Request header is not getting passed to feign calls while calling via Async

Tags: asynchronous, http-headers, completable-future, spring-cloud-feign

i have rest service runs in spring-boot. i am trying to make inter microservice rest calls using completable future with Async for all inter rest calls.

while doing so, request headers trimmed in feign calls. not sure how to solve this ? ( i have some cusotm headers passed to rest service the same headers needs to be passed for inter microservice calls as well.